# Creating json array with php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to create json array to fill a datatable with code in php
The fields should be:

```
{
 "data": [
    {
        "RecordID": 1,
        "OrderID": "61715-075",
        "Country": "China",
        "ShipCountry": "CN",
    },
    {
        "RecordID": 2,
        "OrderID": "63629-4697",
        "Country": "Indonesia",
        "ShipCountry": "ID",

    },
    {
        "RecordID": 3,
        "OrderID": "68084-123",
        "Country": "Argentina",
        "ShipCountry": "AR",
    }
    ]
}
```

I tried to do this just for testing the  fields
                $array = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four');

```
            foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                $temp['data'] = array(
                            'RecordID' => 1, 
                            'Country' => "Indonesia",
                            'CompanyName' => "Indonesia"

                        );


                echo json_encode($temp);
            }
```

But its returning

```
{"data":{"RecordID":1,"Country":"Indonesia","CompanyName":"Indonesia"}}{"data":{"RecordID":1,"Country":"Indonesia","CompanyName":"Indonesia"}}{"data":{"RecordID":1,"Country":"Indonesia","CompanyName":"Indonesia"}}{"data":{"RecordID":1,"Country":"Indonesia","CompanyName":"Indonesia"}}
```

Comment: Try - `$temp['data'] = array ....` & `json_encode` outside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You are building multiple JSON-strings. To have one containing all your data, all you have to do is to encode the most outer array (in your case this seems to be `$array`).

So doing this is enough:

`echo json_encode($array);`

You have to call the `json_encode` function after you are done preparing your data, so in this case after your loop.